# undefined method `sub' for #<Array:0x007fcdb436ad38> Jcrop with rails & mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Hi I am using MongoDB with Rails, in that i am using paperclip and Jcrop for image Cropping.
But i am getting this error. Please help me.

```
undefined method `sub' for #<Array:0x007fcdb436ad38>
        crop_command + super.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '')
```

---

### Model.rb

```
as_mongoid_attached_file :doctor_avatar,
:styles  => { :small => "100x100#", :large => "500x500>" }, 
:processors => [:cropper]
attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
after_update :reprocess_avatar, :if => :cropping?

def cropping?
     !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
end

private

def reprocess_avatar
doctor_avatar.reprocess!
end
```

### Cropper.rb

```
module Paperclip
class Cropper < Thumbnail
def transformation_command
if crop_command
     crop_command + super.first.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '')
else
     super
  end
end

def crop_command

target = @attachment.instance
    if target.cropping?
      " -crop '#{target.crop_w.to_i}x#{target.crop_h.to_i}+#{target.crop_x.to_i}+#{target.crop_y.to_i}'"
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: ase mas re @xlembouras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `super` returns an Array, not a String. However [`#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub) is a method defined on strings.

I'm guessing that probably you want to do:

```
crop_command + super.first.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '')
```

Comment: Here We need to use source :gemcutter

gem 'spec' on gem file